# Are there any competitors to Atlassians Fisheye?

Tags: version-control, atlassian-fisheye

I'm looking for alternatives to view my source code repository and run metrics on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at [Review Board](http://www.reviewboard.org/)? It's an open source tool that is used on google code and is picking up some steam in general. I ended up not using it for my particular project because it didn't provide a user-friendly way to do post-commit reviews. I imagine the web interface has improved dramatically since I evaluated it last year.

If Review Board doesn't match your requirements, consider posting more detail on what your looking for so we can have a better chance of pointing you in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

You should checkout [ZebraPlan](https://www.zebraplan.com).

From my experience, ZebraPlan is a much better and easier alternative to Atlassian Fisheye and Crucible. ZebraPlan has a built-in code review feature that allows you to easily connect to your source code repository. Keep in mind that you can’t validate code with Fisheye, but you can with ZebraPlan. You will definitely save time and money using ZebraPlan. Fisheye charges $800/month for 10 users and unlimited repos and ZebraPlan charges $43/month for 10 users and unlimited repos.

Here’s a short video that showcases ZebraPlan’s “Code Review” feature: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Gxg_d-5vuw

I hope this helps!

Comment: In March 2018 this software doesn't seem to exist anymore